# Passing the value from JavaScript confirmation to Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to JavaScript and Codeigniter. I want to know how to pass the JavaScript confirmation (Yes/No) to Codeigniter Controller.

For Example I have a link

`Update all records`. 
(how to link this?).

Once the user click it, there's a pop-up message that says `Are you sure?`. If yes then it will be passed to controller/model and do the updates if no it will stay on the same page.

Or can somebody teach me other approach?

Comment: im new to javascript much more that i do not know ajax

Comment: I have added a simple solution, you can try :)

Comment: Thanks Bobrovsky for editing, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

what do you use? radio button? if yes, just add form tags above the radio button tags.

Here is the example

```
<form name = "yesno" action = "<?php site_url('check/yesorno') ?>" method = "post">
    <input type = "radio" name = "yesorno" value = "yes" onclick = "this.form.submit()">Yes
    <br>
    <input type = "radio" name = "yesorno" value = "no" onclick = "this.form.submit">No
</form>

/*Note:
Form name = name of form
action = destionation url (site_url(yourController/yourFunction))
method = post/get
onclick = javascript event (will execute the code when user click)
this.form.submit() = javascript dom, means submit the your form when specified event executed*/
```

code if u want to use ajax

```
//first->create the object
//for chrome, firefox, etc
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
//fro ie, etc
else
{
   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

    //to get response from php
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
    //your code here
    }
}

    //open connection
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../project_php/login.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();

/*Note:
  GET -> method
  2nd paramater(../project_php/login.php) -> destination url
  3rd parameter -> true or false (use true!)

  on "your code here" comment, add your code if response from php successfully received.
*/
```

Comment: No that is just link, when the user click the link it will display pop message (confirmation message javascript) if yes, update will work on the controller

Comment: ah yeah, i've looked your code below. It seems like after the user click the link and the popup window has opened, it will display a message with link. if the user click the link within the popup window, it means "yes". Am I right? if that's the case, the easiest way is use ajax. I know you're new to javascript. But I think, try to learn ajax is not as hard as you think. Actually ajax is sub of javascript :D

Comment: i've updated my answer. Don't worry to ask if you still not understand with the code ;)

Comment: yes its very unfamiliar. is it possible not to use javascript or ajax with this kind of situation.?

Comment: hey, i've an idea about how to do it without ajax ;). The workflow are: when the user click the first link, then popup window opened with messages and link. when user click link within the popup window, it will redirect the user to controller where you update the data, from the controller, just redirect the user to the destination. How about that? it's more simple right?

Answer (score 1):

This is the most simple solution I can find, you can see a live demo at http://jsbin.com/ecimiw/1/edit

I use jQuery to simplize things :)

In general. I use `preventDefault()` to prevent the browser change the page immediately. After that, display a `confirm` box. If user click `yes` (agreed) then make the broser change to the url in the `href` of the clicked `a` element.

The most important things here is jQuery and a class name for all link you need confirmation (in this demo, I uses `need-confirm`).

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.need-confirm').click(function(ev)
  {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("Put your question here!"))
    {
       document.location = $(this).attr("href");
    }
  });
}); how can i put the link going to my controller

Comment: You put the link in the `href` of the `a` element as normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a form using a link like this:

```
<a href="javascript:{}" onclick="formanName.submit();"> linktext </a>
```

to ask for confirmation before sending, you can try:

```
<a href="javascript:{}" onclick="if(confirm('Message?')) { formName.submit();}"> linktext </a>
```

where `formName` is the name of the form you want to submit. I hope that helps.

Comment: can you please elaborate about the form name because i dont have a form name. It is just a link.

Comment: well you could create a small form for submission of the link. But that depends on your code. Hard to tell without seeing any code example.

Comment: <a id="my_link" href="bets/default/" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to set the current defaults to all un modified ones?');">Update Default</a> - but this is wrong because its just go to bets/default/ it did not go to controller to do the updates

Comment: then it's not the confirmation, it's your `/bets/default/` that has the issue.

Comment: Its become more unfamiliar to me. Is it possible not to use ajax or javascript with this situation?

Comment: well it depends on your code in your controller. The `javascript` part is really simple as you have now. Just a confirmation pop up. What you need to work on is the controller code, which I'm not very familiar with, I haven't worked with codeIgniter. AJAX is not necessary if you don't wanna use it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all your effort for answering my question, I got an idea from you.
Here is my solution.

my link is

id="my_link" href="controller/function" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"> Click here

it works fine it goes to the controller/function and do the updates

thanks everyone